# How to do an inline ternary operation or if else in a JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, if-statement

I have JSON array structure like below.

```
{
    "appName": "MyApp",
    "restricted_mode": true,

    "some_array": [
          { "module_1": "abc", "type": "internal", "company": "Google", "storage": "cloud" },
          { "module_2": "xyz", "type": "external", "company": "Amazon", "storage": "local" },
      ]
}
```

Above works great but is it possible to set `type` of `module_2` to `external` only if `restricted_mode` is set to `false`? How can I do an inline `ternary` operation or `if else` here?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. JSON doesn't do conditional statements, but if you programmatically create this file, you can do it there

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(a.restricted_mode === false){
    a.some_array[1].type = "external"
}
```

you can write this code after creating your json

Comment: Can you please fit this logic into the code snippet I provided? I meant that I need to know if its possible to inline the logic in an array I declared in my question.